# Making a drawing game using phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I am developing a game using **Phaser** where a user is rendered a triangular canvas. User can crop this canvas to any possible shape by drawing any crop pattern on the canvas. Besides this, i need to get this cropped canvas in suitable data format to be used as an image to render and also trace changes made on this canvas for undoing puspose.
Any help to get this through will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[Initial canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLCxi.png)

[Canvas after crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVSoq.png)
[Cropped canvas used to create new canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NInXI.png)

Answer (score 2):

So it's like folding a piece of paper and then cutting it so it looks like a snowflake? Interesting idea.

I think you could either use [BitmapData](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/category/bitmapdata) to draw the initial cut out, then copy that bitmap 6 (or 12?) times and rotate and flip x-axis to construct the rest. Though maybe there will be seems, so like small lines, between the parts idk.

Another appproach would be to keep track of the initial cutlines like vectors. Then use math/trigonometry to calculate the result. No idea how to do this though, sorry.